# Storing values into a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I am trying to Redim an array with multiple columns like:

```
Dim f() as Variant
ReDim f(0 To 0, 0 To 0) As Variant
ReDim Preserve f(0 To UBound(f), 0 To UBound(f))
```

To obtain something like this:

```
[15   34   70]
```

When I try to store into the array, I am doing as:

```
f(0,i) = ...
f(1,i) = ...
f(2,i) = ...
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `UBound(f)` is zero. When you exactly make it size of 3? Also it is one dimensional [15 34 70]. What do you mean by multi-dimensional?

Comment: For each column I am using a different formula.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're asking. Show the actual code and the actual problem.

Comment: It is already solved. I was trying to `ReDim Preserve f(0 To UBound(f), 0 To Ubound(f))` when the multidimensional array was already dimensioned `ReDim f(0 To 0, 0 To 0) As Variant`

Comment: If it's solved show us the answer. Post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create an array with 1 row and 3 columns where the number of columns could increase. First, I needed to re-dimension the empty array (`Dim f() As Variant`) as follows (`ReDim f(0 To a, 0 To 3)`). The above code was not working since I was trying to Redim the array that was already dimensioned.

Second, I wanted the array to return:

```
f(0,i) = "Bring the value from, for instance, cells A9"
f(0,i+1) = "Bring the value from, for instance, cells A16"
f(0,i+2) = "Bring the value from, for instance, cells G16"
```